# Frequent HTTP 500 Internal Errors with Google Drive drive.files.get API

Tags: python, google-drive-api

We have a service which is highly dependent on Google Drive (it uses [the Python SDK](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/)), our service goes through Google Drive collections and files.

Checking the production log, we found that there are many HTTP 500 Server Internal Errors when we call Google Drive's `drive.files.get` API endpoint. The error rate is about 0.5%. After investigating, I found that the extreme case is continuous 9 HTTP 500 failure in one hour.

The exceptions look like this:

```
  File "/home/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx/storage.py", line 1185, in get_file
    gdrive_file = self.client.files().get(fileId='0Bxn2GmQxR4zHYlNvaUlFNjl6MkE', fields='id,title,modifiedDate,createdDate,fileSize,mimeType,downloadUrl,labels').execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apiclient/http.py", line 389, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, self.uri)
HttpError: <HttpError 500 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Bxn2GmQxR4zHYlNvaUlFNjl6MkE?fields=id%2Ctitle%2CmodifiedDate%2CcreatedDate%2CfileSize%2CmimeType%2CdownloadUrl%2Clabels&alt=json returned "Internal Error">
```

Our service is hosted on Amazon Web Service, in the US WEST-2 data center.

Has anyone had a similar issue? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's approximately the same error rate I see. Just do an exponential backoff and retry.

Comment: I also saw higher than expected error rates, so implemented a retry, too.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I'd like to know whether the google drive API error rate is expected. I reported a bug to google, got no response yet.

Answer (score 12):

Because Google infrastructure is complex, large scale and distributed it is close to impossible to have a 0% error rate - servers or hard disks dying during the request, unexpected timeouts between servers internally, datacenter outage or increased load, tentative DOS attacks, misbehaving applications... - all of which might raise the 500's error rate - so as a general good practice, implementing an exponential backoff and retry strategy on your end is good when you deal with Web APIs and actually it is almost mandatory if you want to offer a reliable service, also on your end it might smooth out temporary network glitch etc...

Now 0.5% is a bit high, I believe the global error rate is lower in average but I'm going to bring it up to the Drive team so they investigate and try to reduce this (sometimes it's just about increasing a timeout to one of our server dependencies). We're always taking passes at reducing the error rate but sometimes we have to spend time building new features especially when the products are rather new :)

Comment: Thanks very much for your comprehensive response, I've added backoff and retry to these API calls, so far so good.

Comment: [the google documentation does not cover 500's error](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors) -- also, I've had times where I get `internal 500 error` repeatedly, exhausting the retry.... In apps where I'm uploading batches of ~50 files/sec, I easily get an error rate higher than 2%, which seems very poor

Answer (score 3):

I used [`tenacity`](https://github.com/jd/tenacity) to retry the request. First install it with

```
pip install tenacity
```

then

```
from tenacity import retry, retry_if_exception_type, wait_exponential, stop_after_attempt
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

@retry(reraise=True, retry=retry_if_exception_type(HttpError),
       wait=wait_exponential(),
       stop=stop_after_attempt(5))
def function_that_calls_the_google_drive_api():
    pass
```