# Error from this method google.apps.sheets.v4.SpreadsheetsService.GetSpreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am running a python script and I am using the google sheets api. But sometimes I get a 500 or 503 error

[image: erros message]

I have every few hours (see the peaks) an error Message 500 and 503

Where does this come from?

Comment: 500 and 503 errors occur when the server has an internal error or it is too busy to accept your request. If you think you are getting these errors too frequently, I recommend you to head over [GSuite Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

As you report, the error is "sometimes".  Issue is Google-side.  All you can do is add retries as https://stackoverflow.com/users/6092067/teyam points out:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40072468/9938721

Note: Peter008's question 58260341 is technically not a duplicate of question 40059997 [Google Sheets API HttpError 500 and 503](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40059997/google-sheets-api-httperror-500-and-503) because the accepted answer for question 40059997 turned out to be of a different concern -an edge case rather than a common case.