# service.files().update() returns http 500 error every time in python Google drive API

Tags: python-3.x, permissions, google-drive-api, http-status-code-500

I am using the google drive python API to write fetch files, create an excel out of the file in python and then write the resulting excel file back to google drive. Important to note is that I am executing from a jupyter notebook that runs on an AWS EC2 instance. This goes well through the use of:

```
file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                              media_body=media,
                              fields='id').execute()
```

However when the input is changed I need to overwrite the file with the new excel. I tried to do this in two ways. The first is to delete the file using:

```
service.files().delete(fileId=file_id).execute()
```

and then to just create the new file. Through the method below this returns the following error:

> HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1hLSsfGDMpnvpYTgFpuVS7Suyctc4CQJQwGgcnFuoAnU? returned "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientFilePermissions', 'message': 'The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.'}]">

When I try to change the persmissions using:

```
def set_permission(service, file_id):
    print(file_id)
    print(service.permissions().list(fileId=file_id).execute())
    try:
        permission = {'type': 'anyone',
                      'value': 'anyone',
                      'role': 'owner'}
        return service.permissions().update(fileId=file_id,body=permission, permissionId="0618xxx9047xxx522413", transferOwnership=True).execute()
    except errors.HttpError as error:
        return print('Error while setting permission:', error)
```

I get:

> HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1hLSsfGDMpnvpYTgFpuVS7Suyctc4CQJQwGgcnFuoAnU? returned "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientFilePermissions', 'message': 'The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.'}]">

When I try to update the file using:

```
file = service.files().update(fileId=file_id, media_body=media).execute()
```

I get:

> HttpError: <HttpError 500 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/1hLSsfGDMpvpYTgFpuVS7Suyctc4CQJQwGgcnFuoAnU?alt=json&uploadType=media returned "Internal Error". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'internalError', 'message': 'Internal Error'}]">

I tried the solution metioned here: [Frequent HTTP 500 Internal Errors with Google Drive drive.files.get API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471180/frequent-http-500-internal-errors-with-google-drive-drive-files-get-api) but to no avail as well

I am really at a loss here at what I can still try to do. Preferably I would want the .update() method to work however ommiting the http 500 error does not seem to be an option. Anyone knows how I can fix the http 500 error (or perhaps get the delete->create option to work)?

With kind regards,
Jonas

P.S. I tried to set the service url as owner in the google developer console but this did not help either.

Comment: Do you have the necessary permissions for this file first of all? What scopes are you using for your request?

Comment: Hi ale13, the scope that I use is: scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']. I checked the permissions through the permissionID: {'kind': 'drive#permissionList', 'permissions': [{'kind': 'drive#permission', 'id': '061834079xxx4xxx13', 'type': 'user', 'role': 'writer'}, {'kind': 'drive#permission', 'id': '010577xxxx5xxx0821', 'type': 'user', 'role': 'owner'}]}. Also I am the creator of the service account in the google development console. The drive is shared with the service account.

Comment: So you are using the credentials for the service account to execute this request? Are you impersonating anyone with the service account? Moreover, just sharing the drive *is not* enough - you also need to change the access levels.

Comment: The service account is listed as owner in the drive share tab. I am using the credentials for the service account when I create the service through a json in which the credentials are stored. The connection to the service seems to be working since the creation and fetching of files to and from the drive does work.

Comment: And what are the permissions of the service account for this particular file? If I understand correctly, the service account has only 'writer' permissions for this file, hence the behavior you are observing. You might benefit from taking a look at this guide [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7337554).

Comment: The persmissions set on the particular file are I believe to be owner if I understand your question correctly, screenshot: [https://imgur.com/a/o3Pch34](https://imgur.com/a/o3Pch34) . These settings are inherited through the entire drive for all files/folders and newly created files/folders.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the update; I think I get it now and sorry for the confusion! But the request you are making - is it on your behalf or on the service account's behalf? To me it seems that *you* are executing the request and since you only have the 'writer' permission, you are not allowed to change the permissions (since the service account is the owner) nor delete the file - so the 403 error occurs.

Comment: I tried to delete a file from the drive through the API where my own account was the owner and the service account is the editor. This in order to test a situation where the roles are reversed. The file is created manually in the drive and then set and shared. sadly this results in the error:
 HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientFilePermissions', 'message': 'The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.'}]">
screenshot:[link](https://imgur.com/a/Twdf1Kw)

Comment: After investigating further I found that the problem lies with that the user account that owns the drive even though it's listed as editor needs to delete the file first before the API will. This is because the API does not have the permission to remove the file for the editor as well even though its the owner. So it was definately in the corner @ale13 was pointing to. Therefore I will upvote his suggestions for the points. Now all thats left is find a solution. When I find it I will update it in the post.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem you are encountering here seems to stem from the fact that you are trying to access a file which belongs to the service account.**

Since you only have the `writer` permission, you are **not** allowed to change the permissions for this file, nor delete it, hence the `403 The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.` error you are encountering.

A possible way of solving this is by executing the request which change the permissions/delete file on behalf of the service account.

*How to do this?*

First of all you should retrieve the credentials for the service account from the GCP project the account belongs to.

Afterwards, generate a key for this account in the `JSON` format and download it.

[image: generate key for service account]

Afterwards, once you have retrieved the JSON file, use it (instead the ones you use when making the request on your behalf) in order to retrieve the credentials for the requests.

Service accounts are just special accounts used by an application, not a person and they do not belong to your Google Workspace domain, unlike user accounts. You cannot use them to log in either. However, what differentiates them from the others is that they can be used to impersonate another in the domain such that the authority is being delegated.

#### Reference

- [Service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts);
- [Delegate domain-wide authority to your service account](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account);
- [Drive API Resolve errors](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors).